# Android Screen specific toasts

Tags: android, android-toast

In one activity I have 2 fragments

1. Screen 1 which is related to Bluetooth connected devices list
2. Screen 2 which is related to WiFi-connected devices list

In connectivity manager I am listening for Bluetooth and wifi connectivities and I am able to get the event when it is turn on or off and showing the toasts based on it. I tried to implement screen-specific toasts(Bluetooth toasts should not display in Wifi screen vise versa.) using Event Bus by publishing an event from Connectivity manager and subscribed in specific screens.

Is there any better approach other than this Event Bus publish-subscribe approach?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData) is better because it has a number of advantages over EventBus:

- It is a component of Android Jetpack, so you don't need to add another library
- No need to handle the life cycle of Fragment, using EventBus you must register in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`.
- It helps you to get rid of writing more code like define event classes, write public methods, declare annotations.